# Total count of main folder using sql-server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please look into this. I have a table in my db with 2 fields ID and path.

table1

```
ID path
1   c:\1\a\
2   c:\1\a\b\
3   c:\1\a\b\c\
4   c:\1\b\
5   c:\2\a1\
6   c:\2\a1\b1\
```

> I have 3 files with id 1 in the folder location c:\1\a\
>
> I have 2 files with id 2 in the folder location c:\1\a\b\
>
> I have 4 files with id 2 in the folder location c\1\a\b\c\
>
> I have 1 files with id 2 in the folder location c:\1\b\
>
> I have 6 files with id 2 in the folder location c:\2\a1\
>
> I have 5 files with id 2 in the folder location c:\2\a1\b1\

I have the query for the count for individual files.

```
select count(*) as count,path from table1 group by path
```

**The above query produces the below result:**

```
path         count
c:\1\a\        3
c:\1\a\b\      2
c:\1\a\b\c\    4
c:\1\b\        1
c:\2\a1\       6
c:\2\a1\b1\    5
```

The thing i need here is count according to top level folder.

here top level folders are 1 and 2 and the remaining are subfolders

```
 Expected Output:

    path   count
    C:\1\   10
    C:\2\   11
```

Comment: SQL tiring/boring?  Perish the thought!

Comment: Post the code you wrote to do this and explain specifically which exact part of that code is not working correctly.

Comment: Let's see, you need to know how to group by the first 5 characters of a string and get a count?   Is that right?

Comment: Search twice for `\ ` with charindex, then use `left` and group by with it.

Answer (score 0):

If the top level folder name can always be expected to be 1 character, then you can just do

```
select count(1), substr(path,1, 5)
from your_table
group by substr(path,1, 5)
```

Or if not, try this:

```
select count(1), substr(path,1, charindex('\', path, 4))
from your_table
group by substr(path,1, charindex('\', path, 4))
```

Comment: thanks for this, what if that wouldn't be 1 ? Can this be done with wildcards?

Answer (score 0):

Please, try this query:

```
select SUBSTRING(path, 0, CHARINDEX('\', path, CHARINDEX('\', path, 0) + 1) + 1) as root, count(*) as count
from (VALUES (1, 'c:\111\a\'),(2, 'c:\111\a\'), (3, 'c:\11\a\b\c\'), (4, 'c:\11\b\'), (5, 'c:\2222\a1\'), (6, 'c:\222\a1\b1\')) as table1 (id, path)
group by SUBSTRING(path, 0, CHARINDEX('\', path, CHARINDEX('\', path, 0) + 1) + 1)
```